# Pull json from aws every 5 minutes and push the infomation to client side using nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using [aws4](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) to sign and pull json data from aws server. I get all the json needed. But I want to pull data every 5 minutes and then push the data to client side. 
I am trying to use

```
  setInterval(function() {});
```

But it gives me errors and the app is crashed after the 2nd interval. 
The 1st error is on the 1st interval

```
  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
```

the 2nd interval give me this error:

```
C:path\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:956
if (err) return req.next(err);
                    ^
TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (C:\path\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:956:25)
```

I also have another problem is that when I launch the web, I have to wait for 5 minutes for the web launch because the setInterval is set to 5 minutes :(

Here is the code

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var opts2 = {
        method: 'POST',
        host: host,
        path: '/myPath/getMyJson',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    aws4.sign(opts2, {accessKeyId: config.awsAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretAccessKey});


    setInterval(function() {
      var myStuff= [];
      var responseString = "";
      var req = https.request(opts2, function(res2) {
         res2.on("data", function (data) {
            responseString += data;  // save all the data from response
         });
         res2.on("end", function () {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
            myStuff= jsonObject.results;
            res.render('myTest', { myStuff: JSON.stringify(myStuff) });

         });
      });
    },500000);
 });
```

Comment: How do you want to "send" the data to the client? An HTTP client makes a request, receives a response, then disconnects, so it is no longer connected. If you want to push data to a client, you'll need to use sockets (e.g. socket.io or something similar): in that situation, a channel is kept open between the client and server, and you can send data at any time. The client will need to listen on the socket and handle any received data.

Comment: Alternatively, as you are actually polling the remote server, you could have the client make requests at regular intervals and have your node.js server just forward the request.

Comment: I have socket.io trying to pull the request, but I have no idea how can I pull the request and make server give me newer data. Here is the socket.io on client side: 

        setInterval(function() {
            socket.emit('reqevent', {newdata: 'data'});
        },4000);

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to get new data on server side every x minutes. That is why I am trying to use setInterval, but it seems doesnt work.

Comment: If you use sockets, then you don't need `setInterval` on the client side: use it on the server, fetch from the source and send the data to the socket(s) that need it. If you use `setInterval` on the client, you don't need sockets, just regular HTTP requests.

Comment: Is that will refresh the webpage? I dont want to refresh the whole webpage because I am actually trying to get realtime location from serverside to pass to client side so that I can update the marker. I use this on server side setInterval(function() {


                socket.send('This is a message from the server!  ' + new Date().getTime());
            },20000); , but still have no idea how can i fetch the data from aws (above code) to combine with the socket.